# How can I write queries as fast as possible in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

I'm looking for two things:

1. Awesome manual about writing fast MySQL queries.
2. Tool which will decompose my query into discrete steps, and give estimations of each step.

I've seen [the next tool](http://sql-ex.ru/perfcon.php), but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can Google to find this information - then come back to us if you have specific issues. Take the tour and check out the "help us to help you" blog (both at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used HeidiSQL for a while and it have very useful profiling feature that allow to get detailed profile of query execution. Also `EXPLAIN` is the first tool you have to learn.

Less obvious is that you have to place your databases on the filesystem with `noatime` option. Each time some software read/write from/to the disk, another implicit write(s) performed - to update "last access time" for accessed files. When `noatime` active that time is not updated and overall iops is halved.

Comment: Afaik mysql `mmap()`s its database files, and such writes ignore `noatime()`.